# Vacation tracker

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have an issue I cannot wrap my brain around. I am creating an employee vacation tracker, and I have already multiple sheets with different data, i.e. one consists of Google Form answers about when the employee wants to take time off work for holidays. Please note that I also already have data on employee availability each standard day of the workweek.

Alright, onto the problem. Let's say 'Lukas' is a part-time employee and only works Tuesdays, Wednesdays, and Fridays. He sends in his vacation plan: he will be enjoying the seaside from 1.8. until 15.8. How on earth can I combine multiple sheets and data in such a way, to only count his holidays by his actual workdays? I can not even begin to write the formula - this is where I should note I am a beginner at Sheets.

Comment: Welcome. Please [edit] your question according to [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright - I took a look at your mock-up sheet, I must admit it's still felt somewhat unorganized.

Due to the lack of enough dummy data and without being certain whether or not you empty/refresh the weekly availability tabs (I'd recommend you not to do so), it wasn't fully clear what you wanted.

Nonetheless, I couldn't resist, I've been working on several projects and your topic gave me some creative inspiration, so I went ahead and did a major rebuild in your mock-sheet.

Should you want to use or implement it, here's some info good to know:

The **Employees** tab is meant as an input field for any coming and going employees; just add any names there and they will be automatically added to the main schedule.

I mocked some more data, so the output might not be what you expected, but;
In the **Holiday overview** tab you can see all employees with the days they've taken, planned, and left.

In the **Schedule Dashboard** tab, you will find three main sections.

1. The working schedule based on the data from the **Weekly Availability** tab of which I guess you manually move over data to from the **Availability Responses tab**.
2. The Holiday schedule; this fully takes into account whether or not it overlaps with a supposed working day, or if the person was off already anyhow. Therefore; **Holiday** is shown when it overlaps with a scheduled working day and **Day Off** is shown when it doesn't. Only the **Holidays** are deducting the remaining holidays.
3. The right one I did based on my own experiences; it works like an alerting sign that whill show you if holidays are approved while still being scheduled, where I work we do this the other way around. Holiday Request > We unschedule > We approve holidays > No overlaps should exist.

I posted some comments in the sheet here and there on orange tiles.

Curious to know if this helped!

Comment: Hey ! I thanked you before, but I think there were some issues in the comment section. I really liked your solution and will try to implement it.

Comment: I wanted to ask you if you could help me clarify some things. I have multiple, so please bear with me.

I find the tabs Holiday Data Split and Person Merge and Individual Holiday Data a bit confusing. 

1. In Holiday Data Split -II- I will of course not use the X,Y,Z as names, but real names. I tried to fix the formula in A4 to >10 so it works now, but what if a name+date is shorter? I also do not really understand the C:D column range or what it does... 

Here, I would like that through the formula the new vacation inputs are automatically written in, but it doesn't happen...